# Trouble implementing Webpack css-loader, error on compile

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack, css-loader

I'm new to webpack, and I'm playing around with trying to create my own build from forking another decent build.

One of things that wasn't compiling was the css, so I did the following:

1. Make sure there were no css loaders currently in the webpack config file (there weren't)
2. Run `npm install css-loader --save-dev`
3. Add loaders
4. Add `import css from './static/css/style.css';` to my entry .js file
5. Make some arbitrary changes to my css to test

Just for the sake of clarity, my loaders looked like this:

```
loaders: [
      { ...babel loader...  },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
   ]
```

I then ran `npm run build`, and it was here that my terminal came up with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app-client.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'style-loader' in /path/to/app/.../src
 @ ./src/app-client.js 15:13-46
```

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here, any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to install `style-loader`. So just run:

```
npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I thought that was gonna be a nightmare to fix, webpack is (very) slowly starting to make sense :)

Comment: Haha I can relate to this :)